# Steepest descent from saddle point

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have the function $w(z)=\frac{1}{3}z^3+z$ where $z=x+iy$, i.e. a complex number. I am asked to find the saddle points of this function and then show the paths of steepest descent are 
\begin{equation}
x=(y-1)((2+y)/3y)^{1/2}, y>0 \quad \text{and} \quad\, x=-(y+1)((y-2)/3y)^{1/2}\,, y<0
\end{equation}
I have that $w=\frac{1}{3}(x^{3}-3xy^2)+x+i(\frac{1}{3}(3x^2y-y^3)+y)$ and the partial derivatives are $\partial_{x}w=x^2-y^2+1+i2xy\quad\text{and}\quad\partial_{y}w=-2xy+i(x^{2}-y^2+1)$, which setting to 0 and solving gives me saddle points at $z=\pm i$.

The last part about showing the paths of steepest descent is what I'm struggling with.

Comment: Tip: Although it might be more or less clear to experts, consider to write down the integral (which the method of steepest descent should be applied on) to be self-contained.